# PHP 1-liner each() with mysql_fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to create a 1-liner to loop through a mysql result set.

Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT uid, role FROM usr WHERE uid = '$this->uid'";
$r = db::q($sql);
if($r->rows()) {
  $q = mysql_fetch_assoc($r->result);
  while(list($k, $v) = each($q)) { // would like to omit line above and consolidate here
    $_SESSION['usr'][$k] = $this->$k = $v;
  }
}
```

problem is that consolidating while loop like so:

```
while(list($k, $v) = each(mysql_fetch_assoc($r->result))
```

returns an error a la `each()` not getting object or array, even though of course it is.  I think the problem is a casting issue, but it does not seem you can do:

```
each( (array) mysql_fetch_assoc($r->result))
```

Any ideas? I like to code as tersely as possible, and having "`$q = mysql_fetch_assoc($r->result)`" everywhere will annoy me, does already.

Keep posted...

Thanks!

Comment: You use `db::q()` and `$r->rows()` ...but then the "raw" `mysql_fetch_assoc()`. What's the point in having a partial encapsulation?

Comment: good point, I could add a method to db singleton instance a la $r->assocFetch() and may be able to cast as an array like

while(list($k, $v) = each( (array) $r->assocFetch() ))

no clue if that will work, nor if it's a correct approach. I'm sure there are other aspects of my framework that may raise a few eyebrows, but I get a lot done with little code in the end, flaws not withstanding.

Learning the ropes as I go...

Comment: this:
while(list($k, $v) = each( (array) $r->assocFetch() )) 

does not work, can only cast variables it seems

Comment: this:
while(list($k, $v) = each( (array) $r->assocFetch() )) 

does not work, can only cast variables it seems.

Ideally one would do in 1-line:
while(list($k, $v) = each($r->assoc())) $this->$k = $v;

In most web app many queries are run (I know (now) that PDO and mysqli can pull off the above), would be nice to trim down the query code blocks and still have access to the iteration to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['usr'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($r->result);
```

or ( if $_SESSION['usr'] already contains some elements with other keys you want to keep)

```
$_SESSION['usr'] = array_merge($_SESSION['usr'], mysql_fetch_assoc($r->result));
```

Comment: right, but that will give me $sess['usr'] = array(of $k=>$v), while I want $sess['usr'][$k] = $v for each property.

probably a bunch of ways to do this, just curious to see how the gurus pull off 1-liner query results

Comment: And what is the difference between those two?

Comment: because I want to not only set the user session array, but also set the object props ($this->uid, $this->role, etc.) in 1 go.

This works fine, just an extra line:
$q = mysql_fetch_assoc($r->result);
while(list($k, $v) = each($q)) $_SESSION['HPP'][$k] = $this->$k=$v;

then, post-login I set object props with:
while(list($k, $v) = each($_SESSION['usr'])) $this->$k=$v;

I use setter and getter methods to avoid manually typing out $this->why = "type so much?";
$this->because = "I like to waste time";
etc.

Comment: Volkerk is correct re: how to set the session props in 1 go, so he gets the points (would be nice to be able to get the object props as well, but each() does not play the game I want it to...)

Comment: You could implement `__get($name)` and just keep _one_ copy of the values (instead of two, one in _SESSION, one as properties of your object), see http://docs.php.net/language.oop5.magic

Comment: now that's an idea, a C++ programmer friend of mine looked over my framework and said, yes, it's good, very creative, but watch out for your memeory usage (the drawback of quick & dirty setter methods)

thanks for the tip, I've only been using magic methods for __call when needing to pass variable arguments to anonymous method.  Did not think to use __get to conserve memory

Answer (score 3):

Do yourself a favor and [use PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

```
$query->fetchAll();
```

[MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) also has a similar method / function.

Comment: Doesn't look like there's more than one record involved here.

Comment: right, just a single row returned.

point of the question is, how to pull off a 1-liner

Comment: @MVC You Know Me: Same goes for PDO `fetch()` method. I understand your question perfectly and I'm not imposing my answer as the correct one, just though you'd like to know other better options. Feel free to accept any of the already submitted answers and even down-vote this one if you think it's irrelevant. =)

Comment: it's an excellent answer, I'm just stubborn and love my db singleton ;--).

Answer (score 1):

You could make the `mysql_fetch_assoc` call part of your `while` condition:

```
while (($q = mysql_fetch_assoc($r->result)) && list($k, $v) = each($q)) {
    $_SESSION['usr'][$k] = $this->$k = $v;
}
```

Comment: That would try to fetch another record in each iteration while the original code only iterates over the fields of one record.

Comment: also a bit more verbose than I'd like.

I think I'll try to encapsulate the fetch_assoc call as VolkerK has suggested and see if I can cast it as an array.  I did see an OS commerce thread re: this problem and casting was the solution, just cannot cast a method call like mysql_fetch_assoc(), but perhaps (array) $r->assocFetch() will do the trick.